# Where can I find the icon for external Drive?

Tags: filesystem

I know a bunch of system icons are located under `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`, but I can't seem to find the icon for external drives there. Any idea where it might be?

Comment: External drive icns are located within one of the kexts in /System/Library/Extensions/. I don't remember the exact name of the kext but I believe it includes the word storage. I believe the file is named External.icns.

Comment: Thanks! It worked I did a find and found it!

Comment: It's located under /System/Library/Extensions/IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Removable.icns 
Also, a bunch of other things share that icons as well

Comment: You can add the answer if you want and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon file for removable drives is located under `/System/Library/Extensions/IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/`, with the name `Removable.icns`.